# GridView Filtering with ObjectDataSource using Custom Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Gridview and an Object DataSource that works fine for Sorting and Paging.

Defined as;

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="oPagedData" SelectMethod ="GetPagedData" TypeName="PagedSortableGridView" EnablePaging="true" SelectCountMethod="GetTotalOfData" 
    SortParameterName="sortExpression" >
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I want to add in filtering, so that I can take the value from a Text Box and a Check box, and apply this to my data (which is retrieved via entlib).

If I add

```
    <FilterParameters>
         <asp:formparameter name="Name" formfield="tags" defaultvalue="%%" Type="string" />
         <asp:formparameter name="showArchived" formfield="showArchived" defaultvalue="false" />
    </FilterParameters>
```

into the ObjectDataSource then it all compiles fine. But I can't see how I then access those parameters in my linq code.

(I have tried adding a params array, or the 2 explicit params to the method call that retrieves the
 `data public List<Dealerships> GetPagedData`
, but then when I browse to that page it fails as it is expecting a method call with only 3 params, the sort column, rows per page, and current index.)

So do I need to define another another method call in the ods for filtering, or is there a way of accessing the filtering in the `GetPagedData` method so i can retireve and page my data all in one go?

I looked into using

```
oPagedData_Filtering(object sender, ObjectDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
```

but that is expecting to sit on my code behind, not in the `PagedSortableGridView` Class with my `GetTitalData` and `GetPagedData` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the explicit parameters to your `GetPagedData` and `GetTotalOfData` methods, and use the [`SelectParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than the [`FilterParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `ObjectDataSource`.